# how to overwrite ng-bootstrap datepicker element.style

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

[image: datepicker_display_issue]
I am using ng-bootstrap datepicker and having issue that the bottom border is cutting of, it could be because of the nested div classes getting applied but I don't want to investigate each and every nested div class to figure it out, rather I want to overwrite the ng-datepicker property (transform) which I figured out thru chrome dev tools is causing issue. Please see the attached picture for the issue.so, In chrome when I click on calendar icon, the datepicker show up with bottom border chopped and below are the css/properties getting applied

```
    <ngb-datepicker class="dropdown-menu show" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate(0px, 28px);">

element.style {
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translate(0px, 28px);
}
```

In chrome, when i change the transform property to

```
    transform: translate(0px, -42px)
```

fixed the issue. I don't want to hardcode the style, want to have the class defined in style.css in angular 6 so that it get applied to all the ng-datepicker.How to overwrite this transform property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a class or id for ngb-datepicker and specific style for it.

```
  <ngb-datepicker class="dropdown-menu show mydatepicker">
```

In style.css

```
.mydatepicker{
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translate(0px, -42px);
}
```

Comment: In Html, I have controls like: `<div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" formControlName="StartDate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 0px">
             <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"
               (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
               </span></div></div>` then what element to apply the class as browser on rendering generate ngb-datepicker tag

Comment: your post was really helpful to me for other css issues. so, marking it as answered

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to overwrite the ngbdatepicker using !important in style.css like below:

```
    ngb-datepicker{
  left: 0px !important;
  top: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  transform: translate(0px, 28px)!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is My HTML snippet

```
> <div class="q-datepicker position-relative w-100">
                    <input
                        formControlName="From"
                        class=" form-control rounded-corner bg-white primary-font-color"
                        placement="bottom"
                        placeholder=""
                        [minDate]=""
                        ngbDatepicker
                        #d="ngbDatepicker"
                        readonly=""
                    />
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        (click)="d.toggle()"
                    >
                        <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

I added to div tag "q-datepicker" class then add the following styles in style.css

```
.q-datepicker{
ngb-datepicker{
  left:0 !important;
  width: 350px;
  .ngb-dp-months{
    .ngb-dp-month{
      width: 100%;
      .ngb-dp-weekday{
        width: 2.5rem;
        margin-right: .5rem;
      }
      .ngb-dp-week{
        .ngb-dp-day{
            width: 2.5rem;
            margin-right: .5rem;
            div{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}